# Jetty not routing to servlet when web application in sub directory of webapps

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, url-routing, directory-structure

I have a web application that is functioning properly (servlets called) when I place the application folder in the {JETTY_HOME}/webapps directory.

If I place a copy of the web application in a sub folder of webapps, then all the static files are called when I browse to the site, but the servlets that I call via ajax are returning 404.

```
http://localhost/shlaa
```

- calls /shlaa/CommentController.do correctly with no error.

```
http://localhost/mapapp/shlaa
```

- returns 404 for the ajax call /mapapp/shlaa/CommentController.do

  web.xml in both paths /WEB_INF folders contains the following

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>CommentController</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>web.CommentController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>CommentController</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/CommentController.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

  The jetty.xml folder in {JETTY_HOME}/etc contains the following:

  ```
   <Call class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext" name="addWebApplications">
        <Arg><Ref id="contexts"/></Arg>
          <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps</Arg>
        <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Arg>
        <Arg type="boolean">True</Arg>  <!-- extract -->
        <Arg type="boolean">True</Arg> <!-- parent priority class loading -->
    </Call>
  ```

Comment: I noticed the .do extension in your servlet pattern. Are you using struts by any chance ?

Comment: Also you said http://localhost/shlaa calls /mapapp/shlaa/CommentController.do correctly with no error. Can you share the configuration for that ? I am curious how that's working

Comment: @Zenil no not using struts - just got into the habit of ending servlets references with this.

Comment: @Zenil I have placed a cloned application of shlaa in both the webapps root and the webapps/mapapp directory,I have corrected the reference above

Comment: In the first case you said it works correctly : http://localhost/shlaa calls /mapapp/shlaa/CommentController.do . I was wondering how **that's** working. Whats your web.xml configuration for that ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - localhost/shlaa correctly calls /shlaa/CommentController.do, if I browse to localhost/shlaa/CommentController.do. In the application there is an ajax call that does an http get for CommentController.do on page load.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to correctly deploy Java Web application to some Application Server or just simple Web Container (like in your case), the web app (also called **web module**) **MUST have a specific structure**. The top-level directory of a web module is **the document root** of the application.

Here is a Web Module Structure:

[image]

Now, what you define in `<url-pattern>` in *web.xml* file it is just a **logical / virtual** path for some servlet. Again, it is **NOT** a real path to the physical location of the servlet class, but a logical path - you make it up as you wish.

OK, now you must put your webapp with the right structure right in the **webapps** directory. For example, in the above picture *Assembly Root* symbolizes your webapp folder. So you take that folder either directly or you can make a WAR (Web application ARchive) and put it right under `webapps` directory. It's not that in *webapps* you have some directory and in that direcory there are several webapps. All web apps must be right under webapps directory.

So in your case, if your webapp folder has a name **shlaa**, you must put that folder right under `webapp`. Period.

Now quote from the official Java EE docs:

> **Mapping URLs to Web Components**
>
> When it receives a request, the web container must determine which web
>   component should handle the request. The web container does so by
>   mapping the URL path contained in the request to a web application and
>   a web component. A URL path contains the context root and, optionally,
>   alias:
>
> `http://host:port/context-root/alias`
>
> **Setting the Component Alias**
>
> The *alias* identifies the web component that should handle a request.
>   The alias path must start with a forward slash (/) and end with a
>   string or a wildcard expression with an extension (for example,
>   *.jsp). Since web containers automatically map an alias that ends with *.jsp, you do not have to specify an alias for a JSP page unless you wish to refer to the page by a name other than its file name.

In your case, the URL to your webapp will be
`http://localhost:8080/shlaa`

Now qoute from the Jetty wiki docs ([Jetty/Howto/SetContextPathto](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/SetContextPathto_/)):

> ### Using the WebAppProvider
>
> **The WebAppProvider's role is to look in the ${jetty.home}/webapps/
>   directory for any deployable applications (such as *.war), and deploy
>   them onto a context of the same name as the filename**. For example, the
>   WebAppProvider deploys ${jetty.home}/webapps/MyApp-2.4.war into the
>   context /MyApp-2.4. There is also the special root.war reserved word
>   that deploys into the context / . While this is the easiest deployment
>   mechanism, it sacrifices control over deployment specifics.

To make the long story short **just place your web app right under *webapps* directory** to make everything work. 
As for the `<url-pattern>` - feel free to define whatever patter you like.

NOTE: actually the are several ways to configure Jetty, i.e. XML configuration is not the only one. See [**Configuring Jetty**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Jetty#Configuring_Jetty) for the details.

Quote from [The Java™ Servlet SpecificationVersion 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-mrel-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1359158683_648d7620a6cf3fcb359c495ba88a1877):

> #### Chapter 12
>
> ### Mapping Requests to Servlets
>
> #### 12.1 Use
>   of URL Paths
>
> Upon receipt of a client request, the Web container
>   determines the Web application to which to forward it. The Web
>   application selected must have the longest context path that matches
>   the start of the request URL. The matched part of the URL is the
>   context path when mapping to servlets. The Web container next must
>   locate the servlet to process the request using the path mapping
>   procedure described below. The path used for mapping to a servlet is
>   the request URL from the request object minus the context path and the
>   path parameters. The URL path mapping rules below are used in order.
>   The first successful match is used with no further matches attempted:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>      servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory
>      at a time, using the ’/’ character as a path separator. The longest
>      match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles
>      requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the
>      last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will attempt to serve content appropriate for the
>      resource requested. If a "default" servlet is defined for the
>      application, it will be used. Many containers provide an implicit
>      default servlet for serving content. The container must use
>      case-sensitive string comparisons for matching.
>
> #### 12.2 Specification of Mappings
>
> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for
>     path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`.
>     In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is
>     empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the
>     application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
>     and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

---

Example with your names.

Your webapp name is **mapapp** (it's the application root). You want your *CommentController.do* to be accessed via

```
http://localhost:8080/mapapp/shlaa/CommentController.do
```

Then (if all other requiremants like directory structure etc are met) in your *web.xml* you put the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Comment Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.CommentController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Comment Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/shlaa/CommentController.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The first forward slash (`/`) in the above *url-pattern* symbolizes **context root** / **context path** (*mapapp* in this case).
This way it will work.

---

Here are some usefull links.

**The Java EE 5 Tutorial**:

- [Web
  Modules](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html)
- [Configuring Web
  Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html)

**The Java EE 6 Tutorial**:

- [Web Modules](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html)
- [Configuring Web
  Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html)

**Jetty**

- [Deploying Web
  Applications](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications)
- [Jetty Documentaion Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty)

Hope this will help you.

---

## UPDATE

For the Jetty specific configuration see this link:
[How to have a web app respond only on a specific port](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/WebappPerConnector)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is happening.

Just  cloning your application **shlaa** in both the webapps root and the webapps/mapapp will not clone your servlets to a new location.

The static content works because those files are **actually** present at that location and Jetty will serve them given the right location

For servlets, the server will recognize only one location, the one inside shlaa/web/WEB-INF/classes
(since you cloned your app, I assume your clone will be something like shla/mapapp/web/WEB-INF/classes)

What you have to do is just modify your web.xml so that shlaa/mapapp is **also** recognized

e.g : (try some combination of below)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CommentController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mapapp/CommentController.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: cloned application is in path webapps/mapapp/shlaa, I have amended the url-pattern for CommentController in webapps\mapapp\shlaa\WEB-INF\web.xml to /mapapp/shlaa/CommentController.do and I am still getting a 404 when browsing to http://localhost/mapapp/shlaa/CommentController.do

Comment: @peter shouldn't you try localhost/shlaa/mapapp/CommentController.do ?

Comment: No because the folder structure is webapp - mapapp - shlaa

Comment: @peter I thought slaa was your main web application folder. Since mapapp is your main folder, you should put /shlaa/CommentController.do as the url pattern in your web.xml

Comment: /shlaa/CommentController.do as the url pattern, also returns a 404 when browsing to http://localhost/mapapp/shlaa/CommentController.do

Comment: @peter A simple debugging step, please try this and let me know. Set the url pattern as /testing (no other change). Restart the server. Now try http://localhost:8080/mapapp/testing .It should hit your servlet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23383/discussion-between-zenil-and-peter-campbell)